# Trouble getting xy coordinates in Chrome when using Dojo DND onto a Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, dojo, mouseup

I have a project that uses the Dojo framework (1.12.1) and 
JQuery (2.1.4). I am using the Dojo DND (Drag and Drop) function,
but I need to find an XY offset into a canvas element that is a
DND Target on drop. I am able to use a JQuery on mouse-up event to
collect the offset in Firefox, Safari and it did work in Chrome 51.0.2704.84, 
but that does not work for me in Chrome 56.0.2924.87, IE or on touch screens (tablets, phones).

I need to find a way to get the XY coordinates within a canvas 
target for the drop part of drag and drop in at least Chrome as
well as Firefox. I don't know if I have overlooked something within 
Dojo that will do this, or in JQuery, or if something browser-specific
has to be done.

The application I'm working on is at https://avida-ed.beacon-center.org/app/AvidaED.html

I have a JSFiddle that shows the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/56bcrk5s/5/

```
require(['dojo',
    "dojo/dnd/Source",
    "dojo/dnd/Target",
    "dojo/dnd/Manager",
    "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(dojo, dndSource, dndTarget, dndManager) 
{
    var theList = new dndSource('theList', {
    accept: ['b', 'v', 'd'],singular: true, 
    copyOnly: true, selfAccept: false
    });
    theList.insertNodes(false, [
        {data: 'Rusty', type:['d']},
        {data: 'Farli', type:['v']},
        {data: 'Ritka', type:['v']},
        {data: 'Beka', type:['d']}
    ]);
    myTarget = new dndTarget('myTarget', {accept: ['d', 'v']});
    var xy=[];

    $(document).on('mouseup', function(evt) {
        xy = [evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY];
    });
    myTarget.on('DndDrop', function (source, nodes, copy, target) {
        if ('myTarget' == target.node.id) {
            console.log(nodes[0].textContent,' at ', xy);
            output.textContent = nodes[0].textContent 
                +' at ' + xy[0] +', '+xy[1];
        }
    });
    console.log('dom is ready');
});
```

Comment: Read [this](http://grokbase.com/t/dojo/dojo-interest/12cdv8wsdt/get-mouse-x-y-coordinates-from-a-dnd-source-after-the-drag-completes#20121214361npfk388nnnxvkx71h1tngmm). It might be helpful.

Comment: Himanshu, I'm assuming that you intended to direct attention to Shane Green's comments in that thread. I tried adding the code for "normalizeEvent" suggested by Green to the mouseup handler in the JSFiddle, and the resulting "position" variable is empty in recent Chrome, just as the "xy" variable is empty. Green did note that browser compatibility could be an issue with his approach, and it appears that he was right. As far as I can tell, the linked thread does not have an answer for the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More recent versions of Chrome have moved away from providing the desired offsets via "mouseup". The relevant event is now "pointerup". I've tested this in the JSFiddle, and it now works in Chrome. Add this handler:

```
$(document).on('pointerup', function(evt) {
    console.log("pointerup evt", evt);
    xy = [evt.originalEvent.offsetX, evt.originalEvent.offsetY];    
});
```

and you should see the relevant offsets appear in the console.log output. I haven't tested it with Firefox, so you may need to set up handlers based on browser detection.